# Show tracking link for custom shipping method

Tags: shipping, ee-1.13, programming

We defined a custom shipping method by extending `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract`.

There is a method

```
public function isTrackingAvailable()
{
    return true;
}
```

But after we enter a tracking number for an order, the tracking popup is empty.

[image: Screenshot of tracking popup]

Which method has to be implemented to display tracking links in the popup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getTrackingInfo` has to return an object with the url field defined.
The variable `$tracking` contains the tracking number.

```
public function getTrackingInfo($tracking)
{
    $track = Mage::getModel('shipping/tracking_result_status');
    $track->setUrl('http://www.example.com/' . $tracking)
        ->setTracking($tracking)
        ->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    return $track;
}
```